# Could I reapply UK visit visa after four times refusal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, serial-refusals

I have been refused UK visit visa 4 times. First time is 2015 Jan, they refuse visa because I applied wrong visa type and second time is 2015 Dec they refused again due to my bank statement.

Third time  May 2019, I am planning to go UK to attend my graduation but they refused again bank statement and economic social ties. And then I reapply again after 5days later, they refused again due to bank statement n they want to know originated fund as per photo.

If I explain all my financial details, do I have chance to approve it? Please advise me should I reapply again?

Thanks [image]

Comment: See the question I've linked to above. After four refusals you should not apply again without expert help from a lawyer experienced in UK immigration.

Comment: This refusal notice states clearly that **you did not address the problems in your previous visa applications** which they told you about. This is surprising. UK visa refusals are very explicit about what the problems are, so they are generally very easy to understand and know how to resolve. (Though it may not be easy to actually resolve the problems.) Until you do so, you have absolutely no chance to get a visa.

Comment: After 4 refusals you will not get a visa unless and until your circumstances change significantly eg stable job/income, transparent bank transactions/statements

Comment: If you continue hitting your head against s brick wall, one of three things might happen. You break through the wall, your head caves in, or both. We all know which event has the highest probability of occurrence.

Comment: So, it means I don’t have a chance to attend my graduation even I re-apply and show the evidence of fund origin for my bank statement. The origin of funds are coming from my another bank account.  Because I really want to go and attend my graduation.

Comment: @user99231, if there is another bank account, then submit statements from that bank account. Also how are you graduating from a university in the UK without having a visa (and presumably never having been there)?